# Why doesn't this code execute concurrently and delay() doesn't suspend the coroutine as expected?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The following code generates a Flow with a range [1,10]. Then it invokes a suspend function that starts an async coroutine per number and triplicates its value.

```
    @OptIn(FlowPreview::class)
    @Test
    fun someTest() {
        val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
        runTest {
            val range = (1..10).asFlow()
            val concat = range.flatMapMerge { triplicate(it) }.toList(mutableListOf())
            println(concat)
        }
        val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis()
        println("Elapsed time ${t2 -t1}")
    }

    private suspend fun triplicate(i: Int): Flow<Int> {
        return coroutineScope {
            val x = async {
                val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
                println("pre sleep ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                delay(10000L)
                val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis()
                println("post sleep ${Thread.currentThread().name} ${t2 - t1}ms")
                listOf(i, i, i).asFlow()
            }
            x.await()
        }
    }
```

**1) delay() is not working:**

The execution shows this log:

```
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#3
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#3 4ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#5
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#5 1ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#7
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#7 1ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#9
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#9 1ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#11
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#11 0ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#13
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#13 1ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#15
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#15 1ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#17
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#17 1ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#19
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#19 1ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#21
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#21 1ms
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10]
Elapsed time 179
```

Every coroutine sleeps for just a few ms instead of the 10000ms as expected (`delay(10000L)`) . Why?

2. Changing delay() for Thread.sleep I can interrup the coroutine but there's no way to make the async coroutines execute concurrently. **It takes 100 seconds** (10 elements * 10 seconds sleeping) to finish **instead of only 10 seconds** (10 elements in parallel sleeping 10 seconds). Why?

```
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#3
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#3 10005ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#5
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#5 10004ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#7
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#7 10003ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#9
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#9 10005ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#11
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#11 10003ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#13
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#13 10002ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#15
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#15 10002ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#17
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#17 10004ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#19
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#19 10002ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#21
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#21 10003ms
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10]
Elapsed time 100179
```

**UPDATE:**

```
    @OptIn(FlowPreview::class)
    @Test
    fun someTest() {
        runBlocking {
            val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val range = (1..10).asFlow()
            val concat = range.flatMapMerge{ triplicate(it) }.toList(mutableListOf())
            println(concat)
            val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis()
            println("Elapsed time ${t2 - t1}")
            println(t2 - t1)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun triplicate(i: Int): Flow<Int> {
        return coroutineScope {
            val x = async {
                val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
                println("pre sleep ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                delay(10000L)
                val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis()
                println("post sleep ${Thread.currentThread().name} ${t2 - t1}ms")
                listOf(i, i, i).asFlow()
            }
            x.await()
        }
    }
```

I've changed runTest to runBlocking, and now `delay` makes the thread sleep. However I can't manage to paralelize the `triplicate` calls. What's wrong?

```
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#2
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#2 10005ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#3
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#3 10005ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#4
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#4 10005ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#5
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#5 10004ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#6
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#6 10006ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#7
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#7 10002ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#8
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#8 10003ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#9
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#9 10005ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#10
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#10 10004ms
pre sleep Test worker @coroutine#11
post sleep Test worker @coroutine#11 10003ms
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10]
Elapsed time 10084
100084
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Because this is exactly what [runTest()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/run-test.html) does: it creates a very special coroutine environment where the time flow is simulated. It keeps proper operation ordering, but everything happens immediately. We don't want unit test to run for seconds or even hours just waiting.

   If you prefer to wait as normal, use [runBlocking()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) instead of `runTest()`.
2. There are three reasons for not running concurrently.

   - `runTest()` by default uses a single thread. If you need to use more threads then provide a coroutine dispatcher, for example: `runTest(Dispatchers.Default) { ... }`.
   - You should almost never block the thread when running inside coroutines. It makes coroutines unresponsive, as you can see in your example. Even if you use `Dispatchers.Default` then assuming you have 4 CPU cores, it will still take 30s to finish, because you can only execute 4 sleeps at a time.
   - `triplicate()` function is really messed up. By using `async()` and then `await()` immediately you still execute the code pretty much synchronously. `triplicate()` returns after waiting for 10s and because [flatMapMerge()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-merge.html)  *"calls transform sequentially"*, you really execute one `triplicate()` at a time.

     I guess what you intended (?) is to return a flow immediately and emit items after 10s. Then `flatMapMerge()` can acquire multiple such flows and collect them concurrently:

```kotlin
private fun triplicate(i: Int): Flow<Int> = flow {
    val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("pre sleep ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    delay(10000L)
    val t2 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("post sleep ${Thread.currentThread().name} ${t2 - t1}ms")
    emit(i)
    emit(i)
    emit(i)
}
```

Comment: As you said, the problem for delay not doing anything was runTest. Could you have a look at the updated question? Despite the change, it still doesn't execute concurrently. BTW, the reason for using delay is to simulate a long running task

Comment: Ok, there is a third reason for no concurrency ;-P Give me a few minutes, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @codependent See updated answer.

Comment: Suppose that instead of triplicate the function is a call to a remote http service. I wanted to perform n calls in parallel and flatmap the nested Flows. Thus I expected that flatmap called triplicate in parallel 10 times, starting 10 async  coroutines.

Comment: I assume you are more familiar with futures/premises than flows, so maybe it will be easier by comparing flows to futures. Usually, it doesn't make sense to implement a function that waits for some operation to finish and then returns already completed future. Such function doesn't provide any asynchronicity. Instead, we return "empty" future immediately and wait "inside it", we postpone completing it.

Comment: It is exactly the same with flows. Usually, functions returning flows do this immediately, they aren't suspendable and only wait inside the flow. Probably for this reason `flatMapMerge()` was designed in a way that it calls `transform` sequentially and only merges flows concurrently. This way `transform` can be not thread safe and because in most cases it returns immediately, there are no big drawbacks. But this is only my guess, maybe there are better reasons for calling `transform` sequentially.